# Recurring contributions with Webform-CiviCRM?

Tags: civicontribute, drupal, webform-civicrm, recurring-contributions

Does Webform-CiviCRM support recurring contributions for donations or memberships?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, thanks to generous contributions from the community, this feature has now been added.

See [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2557997#comment-11840715) for details.

Comment: I'm trying to test this out but it doesn't seem to attach the recurring aspect to the payment. (My tests center around a membership payment currently). I will follow up in the issue you linked.

Answer (score 2):

There is a feature request for this.  You can post if you (or anyone else) is interested in supporting.  Ref: https://www.drupal.org/node/2557997

Comment: any idea of anything progressed? on that ticket i see someone offering some funding

Comment: Work completed. Now available in the -dev version.