# membership recurring payments using Drupal webform

Tags: drupal, civimember, webform-civicrm, authorize.net

I have a webform in Drupal 7 that is using CiviCRM integration to allow users to purchase memberships. I'm having a little bit of trouble figuring out what the correct setting should be, and not finding documentation that helps. Here is what I would like to happen:

- In the webform, a user selects from multiple membership options.
- They may also select to buy a non-membership item.
- Either on this page or the confirmation page, I'd like to collect payment information and allow users to opt-in for recurring payments.

Right now, I know how to create a membership page that includes payments, and I can see how to allow membership registration on the webform, but I haven't figured out how to get payment integrated into the user flow. Have any ideas for me, or links to documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation lives here: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/120029195

In a nutshell - to integrate payment you need to create a civicrm contribution page - enable a payment processor. In the webform civicrm tab select this contribution page - this way webform civicrm will know that you want to process payments, what payment fields to display and which payment processor to connect with.

Re: recurring payment - to my knowledge you can't do this yet. I've started thinking about how to make that happen.

Comment: Thank you! Will you please share as you continue to think about recurring payment capabilities? This is something my organization would love to have.

Comment: Yes - I will PR that back to webform_civicrm module once I've worked that out.

Comment: @KarinG, you are right -- it isn't possible yet (http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3047/recurring-contributions-with-webform-civicrm) but it would be awesome if you get it working!

Comment: Follow-up question: So let's say I use a workaround to get recurring payments. I use the webform to grab the info, and then redirect users to another page to pay. Is there any way to make what users see at that point dependent on the user and/or webform? For example, is there a user account where they could see the balance incurred by the membership they just signed up for via the webform?

Comment: I think best this happens within webform_civicrm. Should not be that complicated... I think. If I don't get to it before CiviCON - Sprint - I'll put it on my list of things to do then.

Comment: Note to future people: according to @karing "you can now configure your webform such that you can pay any amount (Event, Membership) in instalments as well as start a regular recurring open-ended Donation" https://civicrm.org/blog/karing/webform-civicrm-integration-new-features-added-in-2018-and-looking-ahead-to-2019

Comment: What happens when someone wants to upgrade their membership? Does it create a second recurring payment series, or update the original one?